# Flutter unit test case exits when testing a method with Future.delayed

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart

I'm using flutter_bloc.

```
  @override
  Stream<MyState> mapEventToState(
      MyEvent event) async* {
     if (event is SomeEvent) {
      yield await _fetchdata();
    }
  }

  Future< MyState> _fetchdata() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));
    return MyState();
  }
```

when testing the bloc and adding SomeEvent, test case breaks where Future.delayed is called.

Comment: Is this your actual code? `_fetchData` needs to be marked `async` to enable use of the `await` keyword.  How does your test case break?  Is there an error message?

Comment: @jamesdlin Unfortunately I can't share the actual code. But this is close to the actual one. The async is a miss in the original question. I've updated that.

Comment: If you can't share your actual code, write a reproducible case that you *can* share.  Also, you say that the "test case breaks" without providing any details about the failure.